# More efficient way of removing whitespace

Tags: c++, arrays, char, istream, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove whitespace and store the characters after the whitespace.

This is a file that I am reading from:

```
Map: Out of planet
Player:    Max
```

This is my code

```
istreams.get(characters, 50, ':');
istreams.get(c);
istreams.getline(kill.killMap, 35);
if(kill.killMap[0] = '\0)
{ 
   cout << "Error;
   break;
}
istreams >> ws;

istreams.get(characters, 50, ':');
istreams.get(c);
istreams.getline(kill.player, 35);
if(kill.player[0] = '\0)
{ 
   cout << "Error;
   break;
}
```

Although the `ws` function removes whitespace from the stream, I don't think it does the same with `char` arrays. Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me a way of getting `ws` to work or just simply an efficient way of removing the whitespace

This is what I am getting:

```
cout << kill.killMap << endl; 
  Out of planet  //THERE IS WHITESPACE
cout << kill.player << endl;   
      Max  //THERE IS WHITESPACE
```

What I really want:

```
cout << kill.killMap << endl; 
Out of planet    // NOTICE THERE IS NO WHITESPACE
cout << kill.player << endl;   
Max             // NOTICE THERE IS NO WHITESPACE
```

Is there a way of doing this without using `C++ strings` or `Vectors`. I intend on using `C Style strings`

Comment: What is the output you're actually getting?

Comment: Your question isn't currently very clear. What exactly are you getting right now, and what do you want to get instead?

Comment: I see the edits, but I find it even more confusing. Is what you've shown as "End result" really supposed to mean "This is what I want"?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sorry for the confusion, `End result` should be `What I really want`

Answer (score 1):

The manipulator `std::ws` immediately consumes any leading whitespace. If you want enable/disable automatic skipping of whitespace for *formatted* input you'd use `std::skipws` or `std::noskipws`. By default skipping of whitespace is enabled. It only applies to [properly implemented] input operators (`>>`), though.

To skip whitespace in front of unformatted input you'd use `std::ws`, e.g.:

```
(std::cin >> std::ws).get(c);
```

Comment: How do I use it with my `c style string arrays`?

Comment: What's wrong with `(std::cin >> std::ws).getline(s, n)`?

Comment: Everything! I am using an `istream operator` not `cin`! Also, what happens if there is nothing after the `:` delimiter. It will read the next line, and I don't want that to happen

Comment: First off, you can obviously use `std::ws` with any `std::istream`, not just `std::cin`. So, you just replace `std::cin` with whatever stream you have. Next, you asked not to have leading _whitespace_ which includes leading newlines. If you want lines to be considered independently, the easiest approach is to first read the line and then discode it using an `std::istringstream`. Alternatively, you can change what is considered to be whitespace by using a stream with a `std::locale` with a custom `std::ctype<char>` facet which doesn't classify `'\n'` as whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I incoporate this in my code? I consider all the whitespace in one line and not classify `'\n'` as `whitespace`. Would really mean a lot, if you could modify my code please.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really need to do C++ exercises anymore (well, I do, e.g., in the area of concurrency but nothing related to streams). Based on the answer and the comments you have all the necessary tools. If you need help applying them I'm sure you'll find answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: An example of how to add custom white space using locale.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype#Example

A list of default characters considered whitespace.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use character arrays in the first place. This can be cleaned up nicely with `std::string`. The following code assumes you've changed your member variables from arrays of chars to the standard string class:

```c++
istreams.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ':');
if (!std::getline(istreams >> std::ws, kill.killMap) || kill.killMap.empty())
{
    std::cerr << "There has been an error\n";
    break;
}

istreams.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ':');
if (!std::getline(istreams >> std::ws, kill.killMap) || kill.killMap.empty())
{
    std::cerr << "There has been an error\n";
    break;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d0cad975ba05b72a)</kbd>

Here are some other alternatives:

1. Create a filtering stream buffer that ignores the first characters preceding `:`.
2. Make a stream iterator that calls `ignore()` like I did for every iteration.
3. Use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to match patterns for each line and extract to a string.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible if you could help me with my code, I intend on using character arrays as I am a fan of `c strings`. I am sure it is a line or two that needs tweaking, but it would mean a lot if you helped me out

Answer (score 0):

You can write function to eat the white spaces before the input like in the other answers.

You can also write a trim function to trim the white spaces from the beginning and end of the strings:

like this:

```
string trim(const string& s)
{
  string res;
  size_t pos1,pos2;
  pos1 = s.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
  pos2 = s.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n");
  if(pos2!=string::npos)
      pos2++;
  res = s.substr(pos1,pos2-pos1);
  return res;
}
```

While the when working on stream you can remove only the leading white spaces, when you work on string you can also remove the tailing white spaces.

Note that before a `get` which come after `cin>>` you must eat the white spaces on the stream.